# Laravel: RuntimeException in compiled.php line 7772: when making angular http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, http, laravel-5

Hi i get this error sometimes when i use angular $http methods on a Laravel api. please help me to understand what this error is and anything i can do to get it solved. I have put the error log in a codepen for better viewing.

here is the link to the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzJOX

```
     <a href="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzJOX"> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzJOX </a>
```

Comment: you could just put the error text or screen shot , any way looks like your  `APP_KEY` in `env` file is null try this `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: sorry i forgot to say, i actually it somewhere and did run that one two, i got the response saying "application key [the key] set successfully" as well, but i still get this error time to time

Comment: did you try to copy that code from your cli and put it under key `APP_KEY`

Comment: i checked, it's already there in the .env file in font of the APP_KEY

Comment: undo that and check your `.env` file in the project root.

Comment: hmm, i did and .env file already has the generated key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126418/discussion-between-bmax-and-abdel-rhman).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following under project root:
`php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Do you have an .env file? (not .env.example)

Comment: i have the .env file, and it has the generated key as well, but still get's the error suddenly